# DHCP server as Linux and client as Windows

Tags: dhcp-server

I have ubuntu installed machine and setup a DHCP server on it. Now I want to use this DHCP server as all for my windows clients. I tried a lot but failed. Right now Windows client machine uses router's DHCP. basically I want to set it like every client in our network use ubuntu DHCP server instead of router's DHCP. Any Idea How should I do?
Thanks IN advance.

Comment: What is the error when windows machine request IP from Linux server?
Can you post your topology here

Comment: Have you Stopped your router DHCP and start your UBUNTU DHCP ?

Answer (score 5):

Disable the DHCP service of your router.

Comment: Thanks, didn't disable DHCP service of router. It's working now.